# Natural problems not in the Arithmetical Heirarchy

Tags: computability

What are some natural problems not in the Arithmetical Hierarchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest example I know of is the theory of true arithmetic - that is, the set of all statements that are true of the natural numbers. This has degree $\mathbf{0}^{(\omega)}$, which computes every arithmetical set.

Noah Schweber above mentioned $WF$ and similar. My personal favorite is the theory of true *second*-order arithmetic, which is the set of true sentences about the set of subsets of the naturals. This is above $\Pi^1_n$ for *every* $n$, which makes it *huge*. It's also, incidentally, *recursively isomorphic* to the set of true sentences about the Turing degrees (think of "recursively isomorphic" as just "equivalent by way of a Turing machine", though it's a bit more than that).

Now, one thing worth noting is that everything I've suggested (and everything Noah had suggested as of the time of writing) is strictly above every arithmetic set. There are things that are off to the side, too - for example, there are Turing degrees that aren't arithmetic but compute no noncomputable sets (except themselves). But to my knowledge there are no natural examples of problems that are outside and not above the arithmetic hierarchy. I'd be interested in hearing if anyone has an example, though.

Comment: I just added TA :P. +1 for true second-order arithmetic! Note for the OP that true second-order arithmetic is terrible: for example, for any real $r$, there is a forcing extension in which the true second-order theory of arithmetic computes $r$! So it's basically impossibly bad. Also note for the OP that we can construct explicit (relative to $0^{(\omega)}$ :P) examples of non-arithmetic sets which don't compute any non-computable arithmetic sets. As Reese says, none of these are natural; I just want to point out that they can be reasonably constructed nonetheless.

Comment: It occurs to me, however, that there are several natural *nonempty sets* of degrees which don't contain arithmetic elements, yet all of whose elements compute no non-computable arithmetic sets. For example, the (sufficiently) Cohen generic reals, or the set of minimal degres whose jump is $0^{(\omega)}$ (the nonemptiness of which is not obvious!). Not very satisfying, but what the hey.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it is much easier for me (a non-mathematician) to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Great question! There are indeed such problems.

*Note: by "problem," I assume you mean "set of natural numbers." E.g. you're looking for sets of natural numbers which are natural and non-arithmetic, as opposed to sets of reals which are natural and non-arithmetic.*

The standard example is **well-foundedness**. We can phrase the well-foundedness problem in a number of ways:

- $WF$ is the set of indices $e$ for Turing machines which describe well-founded linear orderings.

Another formulation, of equivalent Turing degree:

- $\hat{WF}$ is the set of indices $e$ for Turing machines such that $\Phi_e^X(0)$ halts for *every* oracle $X$.

And yet another:

- [**Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O). This is basically a more technical version of $WF$, above.

Neither of these sets are in the arithmetic hierarchy. In fact, neither are even [**hyperarithmetic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperarithmetical_theory); they are much more complicated, and are **$\Pi^1_1$-complete**.

Of course, we know that there are problems not in the arithmetic hierarchy by a simple counting argument. So, why is this a "natural" problem? Well, I think it's intrinsically interesting, but even leaving that aside it, its "relativized" versions $\mathcal{O}^X$ for oracles $X$, and its "continuous analogue", the set of *reals* coding well-founded trees, are extremely useful in computability and [descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory). Sacks' book on [higher recursion theory](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422631) is a good reference.

---

How about beyond $\Pi^1_1$?

Well, this is just the first layer of the **analytic hierarchy**. The real number [zero sharp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_sharp), which is extremely important in set theory, is (assuming it exists) $\Delta^1_3$ - significantly worse than $\Pi^1_1$. *Note: while $0^\#$ is $\Delta^1_3$, the set $\{0^\#\}$ is $\Pi^1_2$; this is analogous to how e.g. $\{0^{(36)}\}$ is $\Pi^0_2$. The complexity of a real may be much worse than the complexity of the singleton containing it!* And "sharps" of more complicated canonical inner models provide even harder problems (assuming of course that they exist in the first place).

Weaker than $0^\#$, but still above $\mathcal{O}$, is the complexity of telling whether a partial order is a [better quasi-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Better-quasi-ordering); this is $\Pi^1_2$-complete. Girard has a hierarchy of structures he calls "$n$-ptyx" (no, I don't know why); a $2$-ptyke is also called a "dilator", and identifying $n$-ptykes is [$\Pi^1_n$-complete](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145989/natural-pi1-2-or-worse-classes-of-structures).

---

What about *weaker* than $\mathcal{O}$, which is pretty dang complicated?

Well, the *true theory of arithmetic* is basically the entire arithmetic hierarchy bundled together. In terms of degrees, it has degree $0^{(\omega)}$. We can take its jump to get $0^{(\omega+1)}$, and keep going - in general, $0^{(\alpha)}$ is meaningful for every **computable** ordinal $\alpha$ (and there's that "$WO$" again!). The sets computable in some $0^{(\alpha)}$ form the hyperarithmetic hierarchy mentioned above.

*Note that "$X\ge_T0^{(n)}$ for every $n$" does **not** imply "$X\ge_T0^{(\omega)}$"; that is, $0^{(\omega)}$ is not the "least upper bound" of the arithmetic degrees, and indeed the [exact pair theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969604) prevents such a thing from ever happening. However, if $X\ge_T0^{(\omega)}$, then $X''\ge_T0^{(\omega)}$, so it's not far off.*

We can keep going beyond the computable ordinals via *master codes*, but that introduces considerable difficulty. So let's not do that now.

Now, suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a computable structure. Let's look at the set of indices for computable structures isomorphic to $\mathcal{A}$! This set is [often arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3294), but need not be in general. Indeed, it need not even be *hyperarithmetic* if $\mathcal{A}$ has high enough *Scott rank*! It will always,however, be $\Sigma^1_1$ - in particular, Turing reducible to $\mathcal{O}$. We can also study the index set of a *class* of computable structures, which can yield even more complicated sets, as in [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27588614) by Calvert, Fokina, Goncharov, Knight, Kudinov, Morozov, and Puzarenko. So give me an interesting computable structure or class of computable structures, and I'll give you back a probably-non-arithmetic set!

Comment: Are their any natural problems that are not $\Delta^a_b$ for _any_ $a$ and $b$?  For any ordinal $\Delta^a_b$ for any $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @Demi Well, it depends what that means! I'm not sure what "$\Delta^\alpha_\beta$" means for arbitrary ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (although there are some reasonable guesses), but it is not obvious that there are even any non-$\Delta^{ord}_{ord}$ reals in the first place - so there might not be any examples at all, let alone natural ones. Indeed, if [$V=L$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility) then for the "right" notion of $\Delta^1_{\omega_1}$ ([master codes](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2273183?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)), every real is indeed $\Delta^1_{\omega_1}$.

Comment: what about sets?  Consider e.g. the set of all true statements in higher-order ZFC.

Comment: @Demi Sorry - "real" and "set" are interchangeable here (this is slightly sloppy terminology in logic). As to your example, what is "higher-order ZFC"? Second-order ZFC? Well, then it's consistent that that's just $\Delta^\alpha_\omega$ for an appropriate large cardinal $\alpha$. Indeed, I would tentatively say that large cardinals imply that there are *no* reals/sets not in $\Delta^{ord}_{ord}$, even without knowing exactly what that means, because large cardinals provide "sufficiently smart" ordinal levels of the cumulative hierarchy.

Comment: (@Demi By the way, I'm not being cavalier when I say it's hard to define $\Delta^\alpha_\beta$ in general. One of the things I'm currently researching is "the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that for every ordinal $\beta<\alpha$, there is no $\Sigma^1_\beta$-definable prewellorder of $\mathbb{R}$ of order type $\ge\alpha$." I'm hindered slightly in that I don't really know what "$\Sigma^1_\beta$" should mean for large $\beta$! So this is a genuine issue.)

Comment: @Demi Also, let me know if there are any parts of my answer which need more explanation (I don't know what your background is); I would be happy to add it!

Comment: what about $\Sigma_\omega^\omega$?